# SQLITE next 24 hours data

Tags: android, sqlite, calendar, timezone

i'm looking to select the games for the next 24 hours from my table:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM teamstable 
             WHERE ((teamdate >= datetime ('now'))
             AND (teamdate < datetime('now','+24 hours')))
             ORDER BY teamdate";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

But the result is strange because I have only tomorrow's games:

```
String teamDate48 = "2015-03-08 21:30";
.
.
String teamDate54 = "2015-03-08 13:00";
```

I should also have today's games:

```
String teamDate41 = "2015-03-07 20:30";
.
.
String teamDate47 = "2015-03-07 19:00";
```

If it's relevant, I'm formatting dates to local time in this operation as well:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

Date datex = null;
try 
{
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    datex = sdf.parse(tdate111);
    System.out.println(datex);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

My guess is: the problem is caused by the difference in time zone between my phone (GMT) and the stored dates (America/New_York). Could that cause this?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: @CL. can you be more precise, please? should i use 'strftime' instead of datetime or i need to add ":SS" to my strings

Comment: @nate-barbettini Thanks for the great Improvements, i have to learn more english.. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) says about the date/time functions:

> Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) is used.

The only other timezone supported directly is the one reported by the OS, but in your case, it's the same.

To convert between timezones, use a modifier to add/subtract the required number of hours.